# Save keras weigts to json and load afer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to save Keras training weights in JSON format?

I know there is a save_weights function, but it only supports GDF5 and tf formats:

```
model.save_weights('nage.h5')
```

Is it possible to serialize weights to JSON format?

Comment: It is possible if you implement some custom save format, Keras does not have any JSON format defined for weights

Comment: That's the question, how to do that?